# Scanner(System.in) блокируется по достижении конца файла

Tags: java, eclipse, input

Использую Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500

версия Java - jdk1.8.0_151

Убрал все лишнее, остался следующий код.

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            float f1 = input.nextFloat();
            float f2 = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println(String.format("Input: %.2f %.2f", f1, f2));
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

В параметрах запуска в Eclipse указал ввод из файла.
К примеру, можно взять такой файл.

```
100,0 100,0
200,0 200,0
```

После прочтения этих двух строк ввод блокируется. Но я не понимаю почему, ведь это ввод из файла. Я не могу туда ничего дописать, или сказать файлу "разорви соединение с моей программой", чтобы прервать ввод.

Мне нужно, чтобы программа читала пары вещественных чисел, пока не закончится файл, или пока не прервется ввод с клавиатуры (источник выбирается при запуске). После этого программа должна начать обрабатывать эти значения. При этом нужно, чтобы заранее не указывалось сколько будет вводится пар чисел.

На счет прерывания ввода с клавиатуры. Знаю, что в консоли Linux есть комбинация Ctrl+D, для завершения ввода. Но в консоле Eclipse или Windows аналогов не нашел. Предположим, что это возможно.

Есть вариант указывать в конце файла кодовое слово для его окончания, но это некрасиво.

Comment: Если заменить System.in на FileInputStream, то код заработает. Но это не то, что нужно. Похоже некорректно работает Eclipse в передаче файла на стандартный вход, зажевывая его окончание.

Comment: Есть бага https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513713 от 15.03.2017

Comment: Создаешь поток, туда пишешь, потом поосылаешь EOF - это кодовое слово.

Comment: @RomanC, кто будет писать в поток и посылать EOF? Основная программа не должна знать откуда ей присылают данные: из консоли или из файла. В командной строке Windows код работает как надо (с небольшими изменениями).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока есть бага в Eclipse придется запускать из командной строки или создавать файлы запуска конкретной конфигурации.

Единственное, нужно изменить в коде hasNextLine на hasNextFloat. В этом случае цикл прервется при вводе любого слова.